# Why is forEach looping over the first value twice, maybe thrice?

Tags: javascript

This is a challenge from codewars.com.

1. The arr = [1] is the first one in u.
2. For each value in arr, newVal1 = 2 * value + 1, newVal12 = 3 * value + 1, then push these 2 new values to the array, which becomes values in the next calculation.

Correct array returns: arr = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, ...]

Running the function would return the value at ith index so `dblLinear(10)` would return 22.

The array that I return `dblLinear(20)` is arr = [1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 7, 10, 9, 13, 3, 4, 7, 10, 9, 13, 7, 10, 9, 13, 15, 22, 21, 31, 19, 28, 27, 40]. (Showing a larger number because you can see that 3 and 4 appears twice more than it should).

I am not sure why the first value (1) is being looped over again and again. Shouldn't the val in forEach start at 1, then take the next val, which is 3?

I've searched around and maybe I could add `if (arr.length == 1)`, then do a different calculation but I don't know why forEach is looping over 1 multiple times in the first place.

```
let arr = [1];

function dblLinear(n) {

  let u1;
  let u2;

  while (arr.length < n) {
    arr.forEach((val) => {
      u1 = 2 * val + 1;
      arr.push(u1);
      u2 = 3 * val + 1;
      arr.push(u2);
    });
  }

  return arr[n];
}
console.log(arr);

console.log(dblLinear(10));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: For each value in the array, apply those formulas, then add those values into the array. So initial value is 1, which you would get 3 and 4, then value is 3, which returns 7 and 10. Do the same for 4. Then same for 7 and 10. I'll change the variables in my original formula.

Comment: That `forEach` will run every iteration of `while` until the length gets to n or more. So it starts at the beginning each time

Comment: this doesn't give the correct result, but it might point you in the right direction. 
```
function dblLinear(n) {
 let u1;
 let u2;
 let i = 0;
 while (arr.length < n) {
  u1 = 2 * arr[i] + 1;
  arr.push(u1);
  u2 = 3 * arr[i] + 1;
  arr.push(u2);
  i++;
 }
 return arr[n];
}
```